# How to change Current Working directory using AppleScript

Tags: applescript, chdir

What would be a simplest way to change a current working directory (cwd) using AppleScript. It would be equivalent to OS's `cd` or Python's `os.chdir`. Would be great if a destination directory if doesn't exist would be created on a fly (but that would be highly optional).

Comment: [**Executing AppleScript Scripts as Shell Commands**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/applescript/conceptual/applescriptx/concepts/work_with_as.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001568-1148121)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to use with an applications save dialog...

```
set filePath to "path/to/my/file"

tell application "System Events"
    -- Once save dialog is open
    keystroke "g" using {shift down, command down}
    delay 1
    set value of text field 1 of sheet 1 of sheet 1 of window 1 to filePath
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be thinking of doing something like this:

```
tell application "Finder"
# ^^^ or whatever application you want to control up there
    # to get to a file...
    set filePath to POSIX file "/Users/username/Documents/new.mp3"

    # to get to a folder...
    set testFolder to POSIX path "/Users/username/test"
    if (exists (folder testFolder)) then
        say "folder exists"
    else
        make new folder at testFolder
    endif
end tell
```

I'm basing my answer off the answers [on this page](http://www.satimage.fr/software/en/smile/external_codes/file_paths.html) and [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18796948/applescript-creating-a-folder-if-it-doesnt-exist) (or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493335/applescript-to-make-new-folder)).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I am using AppleScript to start (to run/to launch) a third-party application (such as Chrome or Firefox). There is a reason why I have to use AppleScript. When application starts it sets its "home directory" to its default app folder such as `/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents`. So any File-Open, File-Save opens in a default application folder. I would like to override this by changing current working directory to a directory of choice before an application starts. I'm afraid `tell application "Finder"` can't be used in such situation. Other suggestions?